# Install SSL certificate on server (before switching the doimain's dns to point to the server)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

As part of a major revamp of our site:

- retiring old server (no ssl)
- setting up new server (with ssl amongst other changes)
- switching the domain's dns once the new server is ready

Is it possible to get my SSL cert installed and all ready? So i just have to switch the dns when the times comes to launch the new site?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. The certificate and key don't care what server they're installed on. To test it, though, you'll need to temporarily spoof the domain name using your hosts file or the like.

Comment: thanks - the host file on my client (laptop)?

Comment: Yes, on your client.